# $_get and url parameter

Tags: url, get

I have a mvc project and when i try type like this in the url `localhost/index` the url parameter in $_GET is saying it is empty when i `var_dump` BUT when i type like "main" it recognize it and var_dump returns main as a string.

my `.htaccess` file is like:

```
RewriteEngine On

#Options +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews -Indexes // not sure if i need any of these, seems no affect, tried to enable and disable.

RewriteBase /project_website/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

It just gets mad at me when i try access the Index class. If my main page were Main, Home, plaplapla whatever it works. But not with index or Index. Why word index is not OK?

Comment: Did you activate the rewrite log?

Comment: You rewrite only if it isn't a file or directory. My guess is that you have mod_speling or mod_negotiation (or something similar) turned on, which is auto-adding the extension before this runs.

Comment: Besides that though, you would be better off putting the PHP file somewhere outside the web directory (maybe cgi-bin), which prevents users accessing it directly and avoids this situation.

Comment: http://localhost/project_website/main works but http://localhost/project_website/index is generating error as i tested.

Comment: The main is my controller file. If i rename it to index and change class name Index, it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: When i try to uncheck negotiation_module it gives me a popup error, altho it unchecks it after restart of wamp server and remains unchecked.